# How to create a center database on demand from multiple identical databases?

Tags: sql-server, wpf, database, sql-server-2014

I have to make a tool to give to the client which will allow him to make a center database from two or more databases.
I know there is replication and it's the best way but since it's a tool for the client it could not be possible.
I made a program in WPF to insert rows from the databases to the center but it takes too much time considering that there is identical rows from each database and the client wants to update the center whenever he wants.
Any suggestions?

Comment: See http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/105965/44324

Comment: I already know this method but what I want is something to give to the client "dumb person" to use whenever he wants to create a center database.